# What is UUID_SUB?

Tags: btrfs, uuid

The output from `blkid` shows a post called UUID_SUB on my BTRFS-volumes. What does that mean and where can I find more info?

```
/dev/sdc: LABEL="example" UUID="e7c116be-e3ba-4097-857b-12a1f4e9f753" UUID_SUB="b263e0c0-1714-48f1-8706-f97dec03b355" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="btrfs"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`UUID_SUB` shows the subvolume UUID (see [`man libblkid`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/libblkid.3.html) for details). For more on BTRFS subvolumes, see [the relevant section of the BTRFS documentation](https://btrfs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Subvolumes.html).

Every BTRFS filesystem has at least one subvolume:

> A freshly created filesystem is also a subvolume, called top-level, internally has an id 5. This subvolume cannot be removed or replaced by another subvolume. This is also the subvolume that will be mounted by default, unless the default subvolume has been changed (see btrfs subvolume set-default).

(from BTRFS manual on subvolumes)